# Become or Go in such case?

Tags: american-english

The article I posted on my facebook:

> They always guarantee readers a thing, giving word to them (including
>   me). But when the time's up, the promise just suddenly BECOME
>   mendacious. This ain't no joke.

Is it ok to use BECOME this way?

Comment: Btw,did i make any grammatically/semantically incorrect sentence?

Comment: I think you want 'becomes' since it looks like you're using third person present tense, but I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I have been watching a kind of japanese manga,called (One Piece), on official manga reading website for like  4years .but the website do not keep their words more often than not.when they say that the manga will be updating on monday,the real updating date always be friday.it's really piss me off,mate

Answer (score 1):

'Become' is fine, but since you're using third person present tense, it should be 'becomes'.

> But when the time's up, the promise just suddenly **becomes** mendacious.

Other than that, your sentences look OK grammatically, but 'giving word to them' isn't quite right.  When using 'word' to mean a promise, we don't 'give word', we 'give our word'.

> They always guarantee readers a thing, **giving us their word**.  But when
>   the time's up, the promise just suddenly becomes mendacious. This
>   ain't no joke.

I would rewrite this some more though, depending on whether you think that they never meant to give you an update when they said they would, or if they did mean to give you an update but failed.  Were they lying, or just disorganised?

In the first case, the promise was always a lie.

> They always guarantee readers a thing, giving us their word.  But when
>   the time's up, the promise **turns out to have been** mendacious. This
>   ain't no joke.

In the second case it wasn't a lie, just a broken promise.

> They always guarantee readers a thing, giving us their word.  But when
>   the time's up, the promise just suddenly **gets forgotten**. This
>   ain't no joke.